# Sort by date in assets folder unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a model folder inside my unity proejct and it contains around 300 models. All models are following a pattern of name. I have added 100 models more to my folder but after adding the model i am unable to diffrentiate which are the old one and new one? So i am searching a way to find that how to order my model asset inside unity by date? or any other solution welcome.

Note: I Can create seperate folder for new models but it will duplicate my materails which i don't want as i am making asset bundle.

Comment: Create multiple folders instead of having everything in the same place, you're gonna lose so much time for nothing otherwise

Comment: I Can create seperate folder for new models but it will duplicate my materails which i don't want as i am making asset bundle.

Comment: Why would it ? You can remap the materials in the import options of your model

Comment: how to remap? what do you mean? If the separate folder solution is possible then you can answer

Comment: https://ibb.co/cYmLDJy

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan ... simply do it in the Systems File Browser instead of Unity's ProjectView?

Answer (score 0):

You can open up the asset folder in your file explorer by right-clicking in the Assets tab, then clicking on "Show in Explorer..."

From there, you can sort by date, size, etc. and find the exact version of the file you're looking for.

As far as I know, there is no way to sort by date within the editor.